# Different Results from Levenshtein Algorithm in Java when interchanging words

Tags: java, levenshtein-distance

I'm facing some issues with a levenshtein matrix i've implemented. I'm a complete newbie, so this question might seem stupid to some, but i've been staring at this for ours and just cannot figure out, why it does not work out.
Here are the words I test out in my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // just some random words to picture my problem
        LevenshteinLogic levenshteinLogic = new LevenshteinLogic();
        int levenshteinZahl = levenshteinLogic.getLevenshteinDifference("abcdefghij", "adb");
        System.out.println(levenshteinZahl);
        levenshteinZahl = levenshteinLogic.getLevenshteinDifference("adb", "abcdefghij");
        System.out.println(levenshteinZahl);
    }
```

the resulting matrix (plus levenshtein difference at the end) look like this:

0 1 2
1 0 0
2 1 1
3 2 2
4 3 2
5 4 3
6 5 4
7 6 5
8 7 6
9 8 7
8

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
2

this is the levenshtein class i've written:

can anyone see the mistake? should it not do the exact same thing, no matter which word is longer than the other?

```
public class LevenshteinLogic {
    public int getLevenshteinDifference(String word1, String word2) {
        int levenshteinMatrix[][] = new int[word1.length() + 1][word2.length() + 1];
        final int word1Length = word1.length();
        final int word2Length = word2.length();
        // make sure capital letters aren't a problem
        word1 = word1.toLowerCase();
        word2 = word2.toLowerCase();
        // if empty, return length of other word
        if (word1Length == 0) return word2Length;
        if (word2Length == 0) return word1Length;

        // fill levenshteinMatrix first lines (x and y)
        for (int i = 0; i < (word1Length + 1); i++) {
            levenshteinMatrix[i][0] = i;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (word2Length + 1); i++) {
            levenshteinMatrix[0][i] = i;
        }

        for (int x = 1; x < (word1Length + 1); x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y < (word2Length + 1); y++) {
                int notMatching = 0;
                if (word1.charAt(x - 1) != word2.charAt(y - 1)) {
                    notMatching = 1;
                }
                int minValue = levenshteinMatrix[x - 1][y] + 1;
                if ((levenshteinMatrix[x][y - 1] + 1) < minValue) {
                    minValue = levenshteinMatrix[x][y - 1];
                }
                if ((levenshteinMatrix[x - 1][y - 1] + notMatching) < minValue) {
                    minValue = levenshteinMatrix[x - 1][y - 1] + notMatching;
                }
                levenshteinMatrix[x][y] = minValue;
                System.out.print(levenshteinMatrix[x-1][y-1] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        return levenshteinMatrix[word1Length][word2Length];
    }
}
```

i know i can solve this issue by checking the lengths of the words and give them the correct order, but i really hope to understand what's going on there. After all, I've just started learning all this.
All help is highly appreciated! =)

Comment: It's a typographical error. Look at `minValue`.

Comment: 1. You forgot +1 in `minValue = levenshteinMatrix[x][y - 1];`.

Comment: thank you so much - i knew it would be a stupid little mistake like that